# Classify using components from PCA

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pca

I used PCA analysis on my dataset like so:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca = PCA(n_components=3)
principalComponents = pca.fit_transform(scale_x)
principalDf = pd.DataFrame(data=principalComponents, columns = ['PC1', 'PC2', 'PC3'])
```

and then on visualizing the results with MatPlotLib - I can see a division between my two classes like so:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.scatter(principalDf['PC1'].values, principalDf['PC2'].values, principalDf['PC3'].values, c=['red' if m==0 else 'green' for m in y], marker='o')

ax.set_xlabel('PC1')
ax.set_ylabel('PC2')
ax.set_zlabel('PC3')

plt.show()
```

[image: PCA 3D Plot]

but then when I use a classification model like SVM or Logistic Regression, it is unable to learn this relation:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
lg = LogisticRegression(solver = 'lbfgs')
lg.fit(principalDf.values, y)
lg_p = lg.predict(principalDf.values)
print(classification_report(y, lg_p, target_names=['Failure', 'Success']))
```

> ```
>                  precision    recall  f1-score   support
>
>         Failure       1.00      0.03      0.06        67
>         Success       0.77      1.00      0.87       219
>
>        accuracy                           0.77       286
>       macro avg       0.89      0.51      0.46       286
>    weighted avg       0.82      0.77      0.68       286
> ```

What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use three features PC1, PC2, PC3. Additional features (PC4 ~ PC6), which is not expressed in the graph, may affects the classification result.

Second, a classifier sometimes is not trained well as you think. I recommend to use decision tree instead of the classifiers you use, because tree is (horizon) linear classifier and it would be yield the result you think.

Comment: Hi! Sorry i accidentally posted my updated PCA components - i only used 3 components for my PCA in this visualization - i tried updating my number of components to 6 but no luck with classification results - I tried using a random forest classifier too - but same results.

Comment: I mean to use three features (PC1 ~ PC3) for training classifier, and single tree (ensemble such as random forest will make decision boundary you would not expect.)

Comment: yes, using a Decision Tree did improve my results to an 86% accuracy thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of whether your results are making sense or not, you're doing something fundamentally wrong here, which is to train the classifier on the entire dataset and testing results on *seen data*. I've reproduced your problem using the iris dataset, and fitting a logistic regressor, has yielded good results for me:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

data = load_iris()
X = data.data
y = data.target

pca = PCA(n_components=3)
principalComponents = pca.fit_transform(X)
principalDf = pd.DataFrame(data=principalComponents, columns = ['PC1', 'PC2', 'PC3'])

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.scatter(principalDf['PC1'].values, 
           principalDf['PC2'].values, 
           principalDf['PC3'].values, 
           c=[['red', 'green', 'blue'][m] for m in y], marker='o')

ax.set_xlabel('PC1')
ax.set_ylabel('PC2')
ax.set_zlabel('PC3')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Now if we try to predict on `X_test`, we see that the confusion matrix is looking quite good in this case, meaning the the overall idea should work well:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(principalDf, y)

lg = LogisticRegression(solver = 'lbfgs')
lg.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = lg.predict(X_test)

confusion_matrix(y_true=y_test, y_pred=y_pred)

array([[ 9,  0,  0],
       [ 0, 12,  1],
       [ 0,  0, 16]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Hi! Yes that is a good point - i actually have a very small data-set, so i wanted to see the results on the train data-set, but splitting the data-set gives an overall accuracy of 86% - so thanks!